Seeking explanation for simple charging circuit seen in DS3231 module
I'm looking to add a DS3231 RTC into an upcoming PCB design, however, looking at circuit schematics for various off the shelf modules, I noticed this interesting circuit that I can't wrap my head around.
I'm hoping someone can explain in more simple terms how this circuit charges the CR2032 battery, and if I need to worry about battery/circuit protection given this layout. To my understanding: the resistor/diode create a current flowing from Vcc through the battery to GND. However, there's a second VCC source next to the VBAT pin. Would this not create a constant Vcc across VBAT regardless of charge level?

Source: Circuit Digest - DS3231 RTC (Real Time Clock) Interfacing with Arduino to build DIY Digital Clock by Harshil Patel

VCC is not connected to VBAT, there is no red dot.

the battery is probably not chargable

The description explicitly says to remove U4 and D1 if a primary (non-rechargeable) lithium battery is used. There are rechargeable batteries that fit the 2032 form factor but they may not take well to float charging (e.g this battery). In my opinion, the designer was irresponsible to include both the float charging circuitry and the 2032 component designator simultaneously and with no note on the schematic.
